# is it compulsory splash screen must have its own java file, xml file and manifest??

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am an Amateur android developer.. I av got a question... Is it compulsory splash screen  must have its own java file, xml file and manifest? Does it need to create another files for the splash screen apart from default xml and java files on android studio?

Comment: No, the Manifest is unique. You must declare all your Activities there.

Comment: https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/launch-screens.html#

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a splash screen then yes, you would need these files (java+xml, and the definition of the activity in the manifest).

You can use the "new Activity" menu to create the java+xml files as well as the manifest entry for you splash screen activity.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other layouts, Splash Screen is just another layout and it needs XML to define the layout and its looks. It also needs Java to launch at the start and to bind that layout. Manifest is used to define this Java class's meta data as a `Launcher` activity.

However, Android apps do take some amount of time to start up, especially on a cold start. Don’t waste the user’s time, but don’t show them a blank, unconfigured section of the app the first time they launch it, either.

Ideally, a splash screen should be displayed as long as the app is loading in the background and configure itself.

The splash view that you see has to be ready immediately, even before you can inflate a layout file in your splash activity. So you will not use a layout file. Instead, specify your splash screen’s background as the activity’s theme background. You can check how to implement it the right way [here](https://github.com/chatrg/Guides/tree/master/splashscreen).